# Add model element value to @Url.Content issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I just to add some model elemen value to Url.Content and don't know how to do it.

Any clue?

Thank you!

Those lines don't work...

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Houses/@(house.ImageFileName)")" />

<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Houses/@house.ImageFileName")" />

<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Houses/" + @house.ImageFileName + ")" />
```

Comment: The reason that it is not working is that inside the brackets, you are in a c# code block and you can't use any Razor syntax there. You can only use C# expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `@` before your `house` `object` since you've already declared a code block with the first one at `@Url`. But this is the best way below.

Assuming `house` is a valid `object` in the `context`:

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Images/Houses/{0}", house.ImageFileName))" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Houses/" + house.ImageFileName)" />
```